# My microservice does not run in my eureka interface

Tags: java, docker, neo4j, microservices

I am on an application with JAVA in back and Angular in front.

I use spring boot and a neo4j database.

This application uses microservices.

When I run my eureka server I find it on http: // localhost: 8761 /. Until then there is no problem.

But once I start my microservice it does not appear in "Instances currently registered with Eureka" of my eureka interface.

After launching my micro services I looked at the console and there are indeed several errors below and the one we are interested in is the penultimate:

```html
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-04 11:40:28.956 ERROR 18576 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
...
Error creating bean with name 'neo4jAuditionBeanFactoryPostProcessor':
...
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
...
Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]:
...
The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

I was able to look at forums for explanations and he talks about login on neo4j because I think that my problem comes from a connection to the database but for the moment I can not quite understand why despite the forums.

I tried to launch the micro service once I was logged in with my google account to neo4j, once disconnected, and all possible ways but without success, I still have the same error and the micro service that does not not launch in the eureka interface.

I did not put my code because I'm sure it does not come from him. I have friends working on the project and with the same code it works at home ...

Can you give me advice or help me if I'm on the wrong path?

Comment: Can you share how you configure your Neo4j connection in your application ?

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is simply solved. I did not put the same password in my file. yml and in my neo4j

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something related to Eureka server, please turn off your connection with Eureka and try to run "spring boot with neo4j" application first and if everything is fine turn on connection with Eureka.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is simply solved. I did not put the same password in my file. yml and in my neo4j